# change alias with directory bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to modify `~/.bashrc` such that when I change directory alias also changes

---

**e.g.** When I am in directory `/home/user/Desktop` python3 alias is `alias python3=/usr/bin/python3` and when I am in directory `/home/user/Downloads` python3 alias is`python3=/opt/conda/bin/python3`

Comment: You could put an `if` statement in the alias that checks your directory.

Comment: yes but bash script executes when the terminal start. so will it work?

Comment: Switch from an alias to a function.

Comment: See my answer for the complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a shell function that checks the current directory and executes the appropriate version.

```
python3() {
    case "$PWD" in
    /home/user/Desktop) /usr/bin/python3 "$@" ;;
    /home/user/Downloads) /opt/conda/bin/python3 "$@" ;;
    *) /some/other/python3 "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```